# Icon-Bar not appearing in Bootstrap 3 Unless Color is Set Manually

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I'm experiencing a strange glitch in bootstrap where my icon-bar 's are invisible unless I manually change them to a color with CSS. This isn't a big deal since I can get it to work but am just curious if this is normal, or if anyone knows why this is happening.

Comment: Can you provide link?

Comment: The default is three white bars.